# Por que estou 'imprimindo' nesta ordem?

Tags: php

```
<?php
function foo($var){
 echo $var + 3;
}
$x = 1;

echo "foo($x) =".foo($x);
?>
```

Estava vendo alguns exercícios em `php`,então me deparo com o código, pensando que iria  imprimir `foo(1) = 4`, **porém imprimiu** `4foo(1) =`.

Por que estou chamando a função `foo($x)` antes da string do `echo`? Acreditava que o código seguiria o 'fluxo' normal da linha e primeiro imprimiria a string e, somente, após isto chamaria a função foo($x).

Na minha interpretação, onde estou errando? Ou php possui alguma particularidade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você esta fazendo um `echo` que imprime e não um `return` na função `foo`.

```php
<?php
function foo($var){
 return $var + 3;
}
$x = 1;

echo "foo($x) =".foo($x);
?>
```

Comment: Nossa! verdade, que desatenção, passei despercebido e fiz confusão com o return, muito obrigado mesmo!!! Assim que o site liberar o tempo minino para aceitar a resposta, valido a sua